# Semantic UI not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, semantic-ui

I got this code from codeopen
https://codepen.io/monty5811/pen/xVgrzB#code-area
I want this to be embedded in my web page
so after some research i tried something like below.
But this is not working as expected.
Here is my html head

```
 <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Semantic UI CDN</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.css"/>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.css"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('.dropdown').dropdown({
      label: {
        duration: 0,
      },
      debug: true,
      performance: true,
    }); 
    $('.ui.checkbox')
      .checkbox({
        onChecked() {
          const options = $('#members_dropdown > option').toArray().map(
            (obj) => obj.value
          );
          $('#members_dropdown').dropdown('set exactly', options);
        },
        onUnchecked() {
          $('#members_dropdown').dropdown('clear');
        },
      });
    </script>
    </head>
```

Body:

```
<body>
<div class="ui hidden divider"></div>
<div class="ui stackable grid container">
  <div class="eight wide column">
    <form class="ui form" method="post">
      <div class="field  ">
        <label class="" for="id_members">Members</label>
        <select multiple="multiple" class="ui fluid search dropdown" id="members_dropdown" multiple="" name="members">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
      </div>
      <div id="dtBox"></div>
      <div class="ui toggle checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="selectall">
        <label>Select all</label>
      </div>
      <p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace scripts from head and put in end. Here is working code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Semantic UI CDN</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.css"/>

    </head>

    <body>
<div class="ui hidden divider"></div>
<div class="ui stackable grid container">
  <div class="eight wide column">
    <form class="ui form" method="post">
      <div class="field  ">
        <label class="" for="id_members">Members</label>
        <select multiple="multiple" class="ui fluid search dropdown" id="members_dropdown" multiple="" name="members">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
      </div>
      <div id="dtBox"></div>
      <div class="ui toggle checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="selectall">
        <label>Select all</label>
      </div>
      <p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('.dropdown').dropdown({
      label: {
        duration: 0,
      },
      debug: true,
      performance: true,
    }); 
    $('.ui.checkbox')
      .checkbox({
        onChecked() {
          const options = $('#members_dropdown > option').toArray().map(
            (obj) => obj.value
          );
          $('#members_dropdown').dropdown('set exactly', options);
        },
        onUnchecked() {
          $('#members_dropdown').dropdown('clear');
        },
      });
    </script>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: It worked thanks. can you tell me what difference did it made? i mean why not add it on the top?

Comment: You should explain why this works instead of just providing a solution